# DirectoryInfo Enumeration

Tags: c#, enumeration, directoryinfo

While learning C# basics i have learned that foreach works on those collection that have implemented `IEnumerable` interface. So far so good but today when I have came across `DirectoryInfo` I got confused.

If `DirectoryInfo` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, then how does it come that `foreach` works?

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirListing = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\eBook").GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirListing)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
}
```

Please tell me.......

Answer (score 10):

You are using an *array*.

All arrays derive from the [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) abstract class that *does* implement `IEnumerable`.

From [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx#) on MSDN:

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type `Array`. Since this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

Comment: Thank you so much odded.....i haven't though about array in above case....Thank u so much......

Answer (score 3):

The [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) method returns an array of [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) objects. Since all arrays "implement" IEnumerable, you can foreach over them.

One thing to note, however, is that since [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) does return an array, it must get the entire list immediately upon being called. While this is fine for small directories, it does not work well for large directories or cases where you use the [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(string, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325.aspx) with SearchOption.AllDirectories. If you are using .NET4+ you can, and should, use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413235.aspx) or one of its overloads. These have the same results, but the list is not created until it is needed.

Comment: Due to necessity, I have had to create a replacement for DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(...). You can find my code at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130054/21311