# How to get the full path of a file through the file's name

Tags: vb.net, file, visual-studio-2012, path, filenames

I am trying to get the path of a file from the name of it. I made an executable file on my desktop, ***Commands.exe***, I am trying to get the full path of it through a console application. I want the program to search the whole of my computer for the file, (it is on my desktop for simplicity) and return the path, bearing in mind the file could be anywhere. The path I want the program to return is:

> "C:\Users\Jimbob\Desktop\Commands.exe"

***My Code:***

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Dim fileLocation As String
    Dim filename As String = "Commands.exe"
    Sub Main()
        fileLocation = Path.GetFullPath(filename)
        Console.WriteLine(fileLocation)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

but instead it prints out

> "C:\Users\Jimbob\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\get path
>   test\get path test\bin\Debug\Commands.exe"

It prints out the path of the project all of my code is in. In this path, there isn't even a ***Commands.exe*** in the Debug folder.

Help?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

Answer (score 1):

or couldn't you just

```
dim fileName as string = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\Commands.exe"
```

Comment: I just tried that, but it still returns `"C:\Users\Jimbob\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\get path test\get path test\bin\Debug\Commands.exe"`

Comment: beg your pardon.  I didn't interpret what you wrote properly when I first read it.  Did you try John Bustos's suggestion?  It seems more apropo.

Comment: Sorry, basically it gave me the path of the project that this program is located in. The only "Commands.exe" on my computer is the one on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [FileSystem.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127994%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to do this.

Something along the lines of:

```
fileLocation  = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\", 
                        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, 
                        filename)(0)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it returned this:                                                                         An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1076098747-3259325876-2786358935-1000' is denied.                  There is nothing in my recycle bin though :/

Comment: Look at the answers in this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2a027b2-7d4d-4844-bdbb-b577f621d547/mycomputerfilesystemgetfilesc-fileiosearchoptionsearchallsubdirectories-txt-leads?forum=vbinterop

Comment: Maybe even this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130052/directoryinfo-enumeratefiles-causes-unauthorizedaccessexception-and-other