# How to overcome UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing file directory?

Tags: c#

I have developed an application that you enter a directory and it gives you the 10 biggest files in that location. I want to give users the ability to even do this on c:/. But with that i get an exception whenever the application tries to enter a something like c:\Program Files\WindowsApps. Below is my query. Ive tried certain ways of cantains etc. But seem to be stumped.

```
var subDirectories = dirInfo.GetDirectories().Where(d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0);
```

Comment: You would need to provide access to that directly, there's nothing you can do apart from giving enough permissions to the user running the program.

Comment: What type of application?... If you have some kind of `executable` you can instruct your users to use `Run As` and then type a elevated privileges user creds... maybe that's enough, super insecure, but enough.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130052/directoryinfo-enumeratefiles-causes-unauthorizedaccessexception-and-other